# Azure Site Recovery powershell automation

Tags: powershell, azure

The powershell cmdlet for a test failover job is:

```
start-AzureRMSiteRecoveryTestFailoverJob -ProtectionEntity "exampleentity" 
-Direction PrimarytoRecovery and so on.
```

What is the "-Direction" parameter here for? The options for that parameter are PrimarytoRecovery and RecoverytoPrimary. I know that the Primary site to a recovery site is what a test failover is supposed to do but, what would the recoverytoprimary option do? As far as I know a test failover in the reverse direction is not possible. Or is it? Is it in the case of a Hyper-V host without a VMM server? Please throw some light if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They refer to it as "FailBack". Resources - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt637968.aspx    https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/site-recovery-failover/

Comment: @RandySchuman I am aware of that, but my question was if a failback could be simulated as well. Because the failovers suggested at:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/site-recovery-failover/#run-a-test-failover